# dronekit python vehicle timeout

Tags: django, python-2.7, dronekit-python

after running `vehicle_state.py` example, it shows an error like below.

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
File "C:\Users\CVLAB\Downloads\dronekit-python-master\dronekit-python-master\examples\vehicle_state\test.py", line 5, in <module>
    print vehicle.wait_ready('autopilot_version')
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\dronekit\__init__.py", line 2199, in wait_ready
    timeout)

APIException: wait_ready experienced a timeout after 30 seconds.
```

Comment: See here:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

You haven't posted your code so we can't see what is wrong with it, and you haven't actually asked a question either.

Comment: sry PaulNUK. I was trying to connect raspberry pi 3 with apm2.8(arducopter v3.2.1) using dronekit api. i have used the example given by dronekit python - vehicle_state.py(Link below). when i run the code i get error as above. https://github.com/dronekit/dronekit-python/tree/master/examples/vehicle_state